# How to set specify proxy for load server application in JVM & Jboss?

Tags: java, jboss, proxy, jvm

I have a load server application which switches between two applications, App1 & App2. Each App has its own IFrame which talks to a bank, but when the bank returns back data, the load server cannot distinguish which app was that. I investigated on that, then I found out that it is the proxy issue.

As a result, I tried to force the application to use `proxyHost` & `proxyport` but it did n't work, then I forced the Jboss to use the specific `proxyHost` & `proxyport` but it did n't work either. It use a default proxy on the box and it does n't care about my configuration.

Setting the `proxyHost` & `proxyPort` at the Jboss startup script (`bin\run.bat`):
the Jboss logs showed that it had accepted the java VM arguments (e.g. `-Dhttp.proxyHost=XX.XX.XX.XX -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`), when we ran
the application, it would still go through the default proxy settings on the box.

I searched in google & stackoverflow and tried different ideas but didn't work.
Could someone please shed some light on it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the load server cannot distinguish which app was that"? can you explain more, i guess most of people don't know what the meaning of it is.

Comment: Usually, if proxy is not set properly, you even cannot connect to Internet rather than distinguishing which app.

Comment: I mean load balancer, it checks the load. If App1 is over loaded, the load balancer redirect allrequest into the App2.

Comment: We have a default proxy and works fine (connect to Internet), but we cannot force it to use the specific one, it always picks the default one.

Comment: each app's iframe need to keep session or something by cookie?

Comment: Yes, we already did (session & cookies are not the issue). The only problem is proxy which does n't like it

Answer (score 0):

Could you try running your apps with the following JVM args: `-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0 -Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=0`?

The DNS settings get cached after a successful request, these parameters will disable the caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can force an application to ignore any VM arguments for proxyHost and 
just use the default proxy of the box it’s running on.  You can write a small java program which just prints the default proxy and ran it on the specific box (like this one):

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ProxySelector;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import java.net.URI;

public class PrintDefaultProxy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // If you clear these 2 properties then set java.net.useSystemProxies to true, it 
        // will use the default System Proxy and ignore any settings given to the VM
        // e.g. http.proxyHost & http.proxyPort
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "");

        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
        System.out.println("detecting proxies");
        List l = null;
        try {
            String url = "http://google.com.au/";
            l = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI(url));
        } 
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (l != null) {
            for (Iterator iter = l.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                java.net.Proxy proxy = (java.net.Proxy) iter.next();
                System.out.println("proxy Type : " + proxy.type());

                InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();

                if (addr == null) {
                    System.out.println("No Proxy");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("proxy hostname : " + addr.getHostName());
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", addr.getHostName());
                    System.out.println("proxy port : " + addr.getPort());
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(addr.getPort()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically in the code, if you clear the http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort and then set java.net.useSystemProxies to true, it will use
the system default proxy (if any) and ignore any VM arguments.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "");

System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
System.out.println("detecting proxies");
```

Then you run this on your box and passed it some bogus proxy addresss:

```
C:\t>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin\java.exe" -Dhttp.proxyHost=99.0.0.99.9 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080  PrintDefaultProxy
detecting proxies
proxy Type : DIRECT
No Proxy
```

Note, if you do not clear those 2 properties, it will use the arguments you pass to the JVM – but from my understanding it’s not what your application seems to be doing. This is a way that the application should ‘just work’ without having to specifically set the proxyHost – and this is most likely why it ignores whatever setting you provide it at the JVM/Jboss level.

When the behaviour is consistent with what you’ve experienced trying to change those settings in Jboss, it means you can’t configure it in an application or Jboss level to use a proxyHost  and most likely needs to be done at a Network level.